# Render string as html in filter-menu

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm currently working with kendo Grid and I've run in to a issue.. 
In my grid I have a column that displays only FA (Font Awesome) icons. It looks like this:

```
columns: [
            {
                field: "Icon", encoded: false, title: " ",
                filterable: {
                    multi: true
                },
                width: "25px",
                attributes: {
                    "class": "custom-td"
                }
            }
```

My datasource look like this: `Icon = "<i class=\"#= fa fa-mobile fa-lg #\"></i>"`

In my grid I add `encoded: false`, and it then renders the string as HTML.
But I need to somehow do the same to the filter menu. As of right now, the filter looks like this:

[image]

I have found nowhere in the documentation on how to enable string to be rendered as HTML in the filter menu. 
The perfect solution would be to add `encoded: false` below filterable.

I hope someone can help me, thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** 
I'm adding [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr2XQ.jpg) picture for further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a custom item template for the multi checkbox using the [itemTemplate](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.filterable.itemTemplate) function. 
[Here's](https://dojo.telerik.com/UModi) a dojo with an example.